# Does this always evaluate to true?

Tags: boolean-algebra

This expression:

$1 \lor (0 \land 1 \land 1 \land 1 \land 1 \lor 0)$

Regardless of how order of operations inside the parentheses are taken, which are ambiguous, the fact that it is and Or operation with a 1 on the outside will always evaluate to true?

By the way,
1 represents true in this case, and 0 represents false.

Comment: $\land$ works like multiplication while $\lor$ works like addition. Then, $\land$ has to be performed before $\lor$.

Comment: If we’re being fussy, it is simply meaningless unless some convention has been established that allows the parenthesized expression to be evaluated. However, it’s perfectly true that once it has been given meaning by some such convention, it will always evaluate to $1$.

Comment: @the_candyman: There is no such convention.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm aware that there are no convention. But if not specified, the common sense suggest that $\land$ must be performed before $\lor$. Just MHO.

Comment: @the_candyman But those are evaluated inside parentheses, so regardless of the outcome inside, it should evaluate to true because $1 \lor 0$ is 1 and $1 \lor 1$ is 1.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the result is obviously $1$, but I just remarked my opinion on the order of operations. Otherwise, I would have posted an answer with the solution.

Comment: @the_candyman: Alternatively, common sense may suggest that the expression be evaluated from left to right, since $\land$ and $\lor$ are dual operations and hence **not** really analogous to multiplication and addition, respectively. And no, the expression is technically undefined **unless** a rule for evaluating the parenthetical expression has previously been given.

Comment: @the_candyman: $x \lor 0 = x$ like $x + 0 = x$. $x \land 0 = 0$ like $x \times 0 = 0$. $x \land 1 = x$ like $x \times 1 = x$.